# Step-down, ultra-low current kVDC and boosting current

Tags: dc, high-voltage, low-power, step-down

I have a constant current source that can only give a maximum of 1 μA DC but can maintain this current level from less than 1 V to a few thousand volts, depending on the resistive load.

I calculated the voltage of the source by measuring the voltage across a small resistor in a resistive voltage divider circuit. It can also charge small high-voltage capacitors to a few thousand volts, calculated by measuring the voltage across a large capacitor in a capacitor series circuit.

My goal is to step up the current level to the 0.1-1 mA level and maintain its constant DC feature (not pulsed-DC or AC,) so that I can use this current source to power some small devices. With this high input voltage and low input current, I can't find any DC-DC converter in the market to serve my needs. Are there any other ways to step up the current of this current source without too much loss?

Comment: You can design a circuit using op-amps configured as current amplifiers. The op-amp would control the output current based on the input from your current source.

Comment: Please provide details of the current source you are currently using that only can supply up to 1 μA. Does it require an external supply to power it? How accurate and how stable is it? How do you set the current? Why do you say that the current source you currently use maintains the current depending on the resistive load? What range of resistive loads does it work over whilst maintaining current?

Comment: nothing, it reads as though your existing CC device can support several thousand volts of output compliance while maintaining 1 uA. This suggests a load on the order of GigOhms is required to demonstrate that behavior. (Difficult to set up and keep clean. But doable, I guess.) Is that right? And, now you want to have something that can support constant currents of up to 1 mA while still supporting the same compliance voltage range? (Order of MegOhms as a load?)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a [radioisotope electrostatic generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_battery#Electrostatic_conversion) or Van De Graaff generator. You could make a [Pearson-Anson relaxation oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%E2%80%93Anson_effect), charging a small high-voltage capacitor across the generator, with an air-gap or [gas-discharge tube](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/gas-discharge-tubes) triggering when voltage reaches one or two thousand volts.

The output could go to a [flash-tube trigger transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigger_transformer) *high-voltage* coil (normally, the *output* coil) and the *low-voltage* side of the coil could be rectified and filtered for DC a t a lower voltage, but higher current.

What the *efficiency* would be is another question. You might get current useful for some purpose, or not.